# DataContractSerializer not serializing properties of custom collections

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, datacontractserializer, netdatacontractserializer

I've found similar questions from people about properties of objects within a collection, but my question is about a property of the collection itself. In the example below, the `Something` property of the `Collection` doesn't make the trip back from serialization.

How can I make `DataContractSerializer` serialize the `Something` property of the collection? I am aware of the workaround of making a property outside the collection object, but this negates the reason for even using custom collections (the ability to add properties to it in the future).

This happens with `NetDataContractSerializer` and `XmlSerializer` as well.

## Objects

```
[DataContract]
public class TempClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public TempStuffCollection Collection { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract]
public class TempStuffCollection : List<TempStuff>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Something { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TempStuff
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Foo { get; set; } = "Bar";
}
```

## Serialization Helpers

```
public TempClass Deserialize(byte[] serializedBytes)
{
    using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(serializedBytes))
    {
        DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TempClass));
        TempClass storeMessage = (TempClass)deserializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
        return storeMessage;
    }
}

public byte[] Serialize(TempClass storeMessage)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TempClass));
        serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, storeMessage);

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

## Example Program

```
void Main()
{
    var o = new TempClass
    {
        Collection = new TempStuffCollection
        {
            new TempStuff(),
            new TempStuff(),
            new TempStuff(),
        }
    };

    o.Collection.Something = "this should still be here";

    var serialized = Serialize(o);
    var deserialized = Deserialize(serialized);

    // Outputs: 3
    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Collection.Count);
    // Outputs: null
    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Collection.Something ?? "null");
}
```

## Output

```
3
null
```

Comment: Because `CollectionDataContract` provides [Interchangeable Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts#interchangeable-collections). For example, an array has a `Length` property and a list has a `Count` property. If they were saved, it would be impossible to ensure interchangeability.

Comment: Doesn't that make `CollectionDataContractAttribute` and custom collections pointless, since they can't have anything differentiating them from a `List<T>`?

Comment: It's not pointless because it allows you to customize the data contract name and namespace, and item name and namespace, e.g. as shown in [How to customize dictionary serialization with DataContractSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51915801/3744182) or [need to have child by using DataContractSerializer to populate XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26896141/3744182).

Comment: [Advanced collections rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts#advanced-collection-rules) has a table with methods for serialization/deserialization

Comment: Actually, there are two thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091313/datacontract-not-able-to-serialize-collection-members) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501526/collectiondatacontract-serialization-not-adding-custom-properties-datamember) which says that's not possible with DCS

Comment: @ChrisBenard - As explained in the comment thread, applying `[DataContract]` means you get the collection's properties; applying `[CollectionDataContract]` (or not doing anything) means you get the collection's items; but there's no option to get both.  Does the thread fully answer your question?  Or do you need a workaround?

Comment: @dbc already applied a workaround for now. Encapsulated the collection inside the "collection". Fully answered via comments.